# How do I switch Tomcat profile in Intellij Run Configuration?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, profile

I imported a project with two profiles, dev and sit. When I run this project under local Tomcat server, it directly uses sit profile.

[image]

My Run Configuration in Intellij is shown as follows:

[image]

How do I switch to dev profile in Intellij?

Comment: please insert images in the question itself.

Comment: Maven profile can affect how artifact is built, but it will not change anything in Tomcat Run/Debug configuration. If you are building with Maven, deploy artifact built by Maven from the External Source instead of using the built-in artifact generated by IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I've solved it! I tried another way to run Maven configuration. Create a new Maven configuration, and type `dev` into *profiles*. Then, in the *Before launch* tab in Tomcat configuration, add *Run another configuration* and choose the Maven configuration.

Comment: Thanks man, please post your comment as answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Maven configuration, and type dev into profiles. Then, in the Before launch tab of Tomcat configuration, add Run another configuration and choose the Maven configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Run Configuration"
Click "VM Options"
Add this line "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"